# Binary XML file line #17: Error when inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

So, I'm trying to build a simple application that basically just show Google Maps on a `Fragment`. (It's not all of it but this is only relevant thing to te case)

I already saw some of the questions aproaching this problem but non of them could help me.

I set the dependencies of Google Api and I already imported the google play service library but I still get this error.

#### My mapa_oco.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

#### My Mapa_Ocorrencia.java:

```
public class Mapa_Ocorrencia extends Activity{

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(com.example.gnr_p_v2.R.layout.mapa_oco);
     }
}
```

#### Android_Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gnr_p_v2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

  <permission
        android:name="com.example.gnr_p_v2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

 <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gnr_p_v2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

 <uses-feature
     android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
     android:required="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">

        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY KEY VALUE (HIDDEN)"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Mapa_Ocorrencia"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And I got this error:

```
02-05 16:33:30.304: E/AndroidRuntime(12604): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 16:33:30.304: E/AndroidRuntime(12604): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable
To start activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.gnr_p_v2/com.example.gnr_p_v2.Mapa_Ocorrencia}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
```

I've already tryed using MapView, SupportMapFragment... And it still does not work!

Comment: Do you have `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment` in your class path? Do you have the correct dependencies in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: I think so yes, although i am not sure where to find the build.gradle. I followed every tutorial available and in any of them is mencioned the build.gradle...

Comment: Make sure you are using `Android Studio`, so you can use `Gradle`, then helping your dependency issue will be very simple.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse with ADT bundle and i cannot migrate to Android Studio.. Any sugestions?

Comment: ADT is no longer supported, I believe. You just started your project, why can you not switch?